# Probability of success in four free throws

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

There is a basketball player with a mean of success of $0.8$ per free throw. In a game, he has four free throws.

a) What is the probability of him succeeding in at least 3 of the free throws?

b) What is the probability of him succeeding in exactly two of the free throws?

Comment: You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: You have down-votes and votes to close. **Please 'take the tour' of the site to learn what we expect of people asking 'homework style' problems.** Meanwhile, I will try to get you started, without actually working the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will show answers computed in R where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF and `pbinom` is a binomial CDF. I guess
you are supposed to use the formula for the binomial PDF, under the assumption that free
throws are independent of one another:

$$P(X = x)= {4\choose x}(.8)^x(.2)^{4-x},$$
for $x = 0,1,2,3,4.$

First, find the individual probabilities
by hand computation and [in (a)] sum the relevant
probabilities. You can check your results against
the probabilities from R. [Because $n = 4$ is so small,
using a normal approximation is not feasible.]

Let $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n = 4, p=.8).$ You seek
(a) $P(X \ge 3) = 1 - P(X\le 2)$ and (b) $P(X = 3).$

```
# a
1 - pbinom(2, 4, .8)
[1] 0.8192
sum(dbinom(3:4, 4, .8))
[1] 0.8192

# b
dbinom(2, 4, .8)
[1] 0.1536
```

Here is a graph of the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(5, .8).$

```
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(4, .8)"
x = 0:4;  PDF = dbinom(x, 4, .8)
plot(x, PDF, type="h",lwd=3, col="blue", main=hdr)
abline(v = 0, col="green2")
abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]